# Меню в виде слайдера

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

Есть меню, реализованное в виде слайдера. В меню 11 пунктов, из них показываются 6, остальные скрыты. Примерно выглядит так:

```js
$(document).ready(startSlide);

var slide;
function startSlide() {
    slide = setInterval();
}

function slideR() {
    $('#menu > ul > li').first().css('left', '300px').appendTo('#menu > ul').animate({
        "left": "-=300px"
    }, 200);
}

function slideL() {
    $('#menu > ul > li').last().animate({
        "left": "+=300px"
    }, 200, function () {
        $(this).prependTo('#menu > ul').css('left', '0px');
    });
}

$('.arrow-right').click(function () {slideR();});
$('.arrow-left').click(function () {slideL();});
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:"Segoe UI", sans-serif;
}
nav {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 25px auto;
    
}
nav > ul {
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;   
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 0;
}
nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 16px;
}
nav > ul > li a {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    transition: 0.25s;
}
nav > ul > li a:hover {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.arrows > .arrow{
    position: absolute; top: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #f00;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-top: -12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}
.arrow-right {right: 0;}
.arrow-left {left: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 10</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 11</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="arrows">
        <span class="arrow arrow-right"></span>
        <span class="arrow arrow-left"></span>
    </div>    
</nav>
```

В меню href ссылки сравнивается с URL и если совпало, то ссылка подсвечивается(добавляется класс active). Дело в том, что мне нужно сделать так, чтобы активный элемент при загрузке страницы становился первым. Я пробовал так:

```js
var curry = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0];  
  $(window).load(function (){
 curry.css('left', '0px');
});
```

Но не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать?

Comment: ну по сути это тот же слайдер , только надо его элементы от позиционировать - у меня есть отличный пример ! если хотите скину.Если верно сказать называется это ротатор новостей - но всё равно это обычный слайдер

Comment: Хочу, конечно=)

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/LY7c/mKnnR4KfL  вот скачай

Comment: ТО есть необходимо позиционировать ul, а не li? К сожалению я не понял, как мне реализовать задуманное. Какая разница позиционируется все меню или элемент? По сути нужно сделать так, чтоб элемент с классом active при загрузке странице позиционировался бы первым слева.

Comment: ну вот смотри - есть сам слайдер а есть ul id="slider-pager" и обычно этот pager отображается в низу в виде круглишков , как на всех слайдерах, в этом примере сам контейнер прямоугольный и вынесен в бок и поменено событие с click на hover

Comment: Мне нужно решить проблему не сменой ротатора, то, что я его сменю,  мне ничего не даст. Мне нужно, чтобы определенный элемент позиционировался вначале. Желательно используя тот код, который я привел.

Comment: @Alex, да, уже не срочная :)

Answer (score 1):

Как то так. Если я правильно понял.
Пример http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZZaRo

```js
$(document).ready(startSlide);

var slide;
function startSlide() {
slide = setInterval(0);
}

function slideR() {
$('#menu > ul > li').first().css('left', '300px').appendTo('#menu > ul').animate({
    "left": "-=300px"
}, 200);
}

function slideL() {
$('#menu > ul > li').last().animate({
    "left": "+=300px"
}, 200, function () {
    $(this).prependTo('#menu > ul').css('left', '0px');
});
}

$('.arrow-right').click(function () {slideR();});
$('.arrow-left').click(function () {slideL();});


  $(document).ready(function (){
var tmp = $('.active');
$('.active').remove();
$('ul #first').append(tmp);
});
```

```css
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family:"Segoe UI", sans-serif;
}
nav {
position: relative;
max-width: 300px;
margin: 25px auto;

}
nav > ul {
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
max-width: 300px;
overflow: hidden;   
border: 2px solid #ccc;
font-size: 0;
}
nav > ul > li {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 16px;
}
nav > ul > li a {
color: #000;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 50px;
padding: 0 15px;
transition: 0.25s;
}
nav > ul > li a:hover {
background: #000;
color: #fff;
}

nav > ul > li .active {
background: #000;
color: #fff;
}
.arrows > .arrow{
position: absolute; top: 50%;
border: 2px solid #f00;
z-index: 99;
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
margin-top: -12px;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
}
.arrow-right {right: 0;}
.arrow-left {left: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu">
<ul>
    <li id=first></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class=active>Menu 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 10</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 11</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="arrows">
    <span class="arrow arrow-right"></span>
    <span class="arrow arrow-left"></span>
</div>    
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

А если попробовать через flex и элементам с классом active задавать свойство `order: 1` , а всем остальным задавать `order: 2` ?